# Real world examples of PFSP - the permutation flow shop problem?

Tags: algorithm

As part of a bigger academic project, I'm dealing with algorithms that solve the PFSP problem.  Does anyone have any good real-world examples of this problem? Pretty much any previous work on this subject I read through uses a rather abstract toy workshop example.

I was thinking about the process of building code, e.g. in C: preprocessor -> compiler -> linker, but this would only hold true if the object files were independent of each other, i.e. wouldn't have to be linked together.

Answer (score 0):

This made me think of the ROADEF/EURO 2012 Challenge (sponsored by Google!)
If that's not an interesting real-life use, I don't know what is :)

http://challenge.roadef.org/2012/en/index.php